# C++ (SDL2.0) 2d Game

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, sdl-2

I have to learn SDL and make a 2d game that makes a character move in an array whilst he picks up rocks and what not.

How can I open a window and get things to appear on screen?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't really an appropriate question (this platform is more about getting help with specific problems).

You mentioned C++ and difficulty to get started. Unless you *have* to use SDL which has more of as C flavor, you might want to try SFML: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/

Object oriented, modern and easy to learn! Good luck for your project.